# What are the details of consensus in Hyperleger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I don't know some details about Fabric in this [document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html).

Document: The application verifies the endorsing peer signatures and compares the proposal responses.

1. Is it necessary to have all the responses the same when verifying， or most of them？
2. If it is part of them, what is the ratio?
3. Whether it can be controlled by the Fabric SDK?

Document: The ordering service does not need to inspect the entire content of a transaction in order to perform its operation, it simply receives transactions from all channels in the network, orders them chronologically by channel, and creates blocks of transactions per channel.

4. Raft and Kafka are only used to guarantee availability, not for voting. Is this correct?

Document: Transaction is validated and committed.

5. When committing, is there a process of voting verification?

Answer (score 0):

1. The application does not actually need to check anything (it's
   optional but a good way to avoid sending invalid transactions).
2. When you instantiate chaincode on a channel, you set the endorsement policy for that chaincode.  The endorsement policy specifies how many organization's peers must sign the response.  This is actually enforced during validation on the peers (after the peer receives blocks/transaction from the orderer but prior to committing the data).  If there are not enough signatures to satisfy the policy, transactions are marked invalid and state is not committed.
3. With Fabric v1.2 and later, clients can use the discovery service to obtain the minimum list of peers required to meet the endorsement policy for chaincode on each channel.
4. Kafka / Raft are used to ensure that all ordering service nodes process transactions and deliver blocks in the same order.   With Fabric v1.4.1 you will have the option to use Raft consensus rather than Kafka.
5. See comment in 2. about enforcing endorsement policies during validation.